# What is the synopsis of Homer Eon Flint's "The Emancipatrix"?

Tags: book-synopsis

I bumped into this book (it's free on [Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/5699)), and couldn't find ANY description of what it is about (aside from it being among Flint's more famous books).

I checked (with no result):

- H.E.Flint's "homepage" (including searching the site): http://www.homereonflint.com
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer_Eon_Flint) (Not even listed on his page)
- Gutenberg (the best they have is "Subject: Life on other planets -- Fiction "
- [IMSFB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41915). Nothing useful contentwise, but indicates that the book is part of "[Dr. Kinney" series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?9401) (which itself has no Wiki entry either).
- [Good Reads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6328773-the-emancipatrix) - only had a seemingly uncomprehensible blurb of:

  > All told, this particular session covered a good many hours. The four kept up a more or less connected mental conversation with each other as they went along, except, of course, when the events became too exciting. Mainly they were trying to catch their agents in the proper mood for receiving telepathic communications, and it proved no easy matter.
- Amazon doesn't seem to have this book (though Flint has modern reprints from Gutenberg), it only has "The Devolutionist and The Emancipatrix".
- Google only found one seemingly useful hit - there may be a blurb on it in "Science-fiction, the Early Years" by Everett Franklin Bleiler, but don't have it and Google Books [didn't have that specific page](http://books.google.com/books?id=KEZxhkG5eikC&pg=PA971&dq=%22Science%20Fiction:%20The%20Early%20Years%22%20flint%20emancipatrix&hl=en&sa=X&ei=To9CUdGYMoWz4APvo4HgAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=emancipatrix&f=false) accessible.

Is there any good review, or summary, of this book and if so can someone post a link or summarize themselves?

Comment: Given that my "to read" queue will last me on the order of 10 years, advice of "just read the damned book off Gutenberg" isn't what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Apparently the author may have been [killed while robbing a bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer_Eon_Flint).  Someone should have told him that he would have sold more books had he had its synopsis more readily available.

Comment: His death seems rather mysterious.  http://strangehorizons.com/non-fiction/articles/homer-eon-flint-a-legacy/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Science Fiction, the Early Years](http://books.google.com/books?id=KEZxhkG5eikC&pg=PA254&dq=emancipatrix%20synopsis&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lJlCUeDzGLO64AOb1IG4Ag&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA) at books.google.com.  Unfortunately, text is not cuttable from the page (and it's copyrighted) so you have to read it at that site.

Comment: If one scrolls up-down around the linked-to book position, you'll see that 'Emancipatrix' is the fourth and final story of a series that started with _The Lord of Death_.  I'd replace Emancipatrix with that in your queue, @DVK.

Comment: You don't have to copy/paste to produce a summary, you can re-tell in your own words.

Comment: @DVK - Respectfully, wasn't going to read the whole summary to just restate it.  You asked for a link.  I found one and provided it :)